# MySQL subquery omits entire row when it matches no result

Tags: mysql, null, subquery

I'm trying to include a sub-query in a MySQL SELECT statement to assemble a product link when the product ID associated with that link may no longer exist. When that product ID does not exist the sub-query finds no result and the entire row is omitted from the final result. I would like the row to be returned anyway (with NULL would be fine).

```
SELECT s.field_a, s.field_b, s.field_c,
    (SELECT CONCAT( '/', sma.name_link, '/', smo.name_link, '.html?pid=', spr.id )
        FROM sales_products AS spr, sales_sections AS see,
            sales_models AS smo, sales_manufacturers AS sma
        WHERE sse.id = spr.sales_section_id AND smo.id = sse.sales_model_id
            AND smo.sales_manufacturer_id = sma.id
            AND spr.id = s.sales_product_id
    ) AS product_link
    FROM sales_order_items AS s, sales_products AS p
    WHERE s.order_id = 100 AND p.id = s.sales_product_id
    ORDER BY shipment_id, sales_order_item_id
```

I've searched quite a while but I'm just not managing to piece this one together. I look forward to any kind of feedback or solution that can be offered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see a `product_id` column reference anywhere in your query, so I'm going to assume you are meaning that its the `sales_product_id` column is the one that has a value that doesn't match an `id` value in the sales_product table.

I don't think the issue of the "missing rows" has to do with the subquery in the SELECT list; I believe it has to do with the INNER JOIN to the sales_product table. I recommend you change that into a LEFT OUTER JOIN.

```
SELECT s.field_a
     , s.field_b
     , s.field_c
     , (SELECT CONCAT('/',sma.name_link,'/',smo.name_link,'.html?pid=',spr.id)
          FROM sales_products spr
          JOIN sales_sections see ON sse.id = spr.sales_section_id
          JOIN sales_models smo ON smo.id = sse.sales_model_id
          JOIN sales_manufacturers sma ON sma.id = smo.sales_manufacturer_id 
         WHERE spr.id = s.sales_product_id
         ORDER BY 1 LIMIT 1
       ) AS product_link
  FROM sales_order_items s
  LEFT
  JOIN sales_products p ON p.id = s.sales_product_id
 WHERE s.order_id = 100
 ORDER BY shipment_id, sales_order_item_id
```

---

NOTE: The issue with that subquery in the SELECT list (aliased as product_link), is that the statement will throw an exception if (when?) that subquery returns more than one row.  Unless you have some sort of guarantee that it will never do that, at a minimum, you could slap an ORDER BY 1 LIMIT 1 on it, or slap a MAX aggregate around the CONCAT (so that it is deterministic.)

It's also a really good idea to qualify the column references in the ORDER BY clause with the table alias, as protection against potential "ambiguous column" exceptions. I see that all your column references are qualified, which is a really good thing.

You probably also notice that I re-formatted your original query, and I introduced the JOIN keyword (in place of the commas), and moved the join predicates from the WHERE clause to the ON clause. I find that this makes the statement MUCH easier to read, and much easier to debug. It also let's you specify an OUTER JOIN.

Comment: Thank you, Spencer. That did the trick perfectly. And it looks like you understood what I was trying to accomplish as well (I remove quite a bit from my query in hopes of simplifying the example).  
  
And thank you, also, for sharing additional thoughts and best practices with me. I *really* appreciate that.

Comment: I clicked the checkbox to accept the answer after replying to you. I assume that's what you're suggesting? Please let me know if there's something more that I've missed.

Answer (score -1):

You might want to try using a UNION in your query or even use the IF sql condition to set NULL if value is empty.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions. I wasn't able to put a working solution together but that's probably due to my relative lack of experience.